Applying homogeneous boundary conditions to Green's function
I have the following Green's function:
$$ G'' + G' - 2G = \delta(x-s) $$
with the following general solution
$$ G_L (x,s) = Ae^x + Be^{-2x} $$
$$ G_R (x,s) = Ce^x + De^{-2x} $$
Now I'm trying to apply the following B.C
$$ u(0) = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{x\to + \infty} u(x) = 0 $$
which implies that
$$ G_L(0,s) = A + B = 0  \quad \rightarrow \quad B=-A $$
$$ \lim_{x\to + \infty} G_R(x,s) = \lim_{x\to + \infty} Ce^x + De^{-2x} \quad \rightarrow \quad C=0 $$
Now to the continuity conditions:
$$ G_L (x=s , s) = G_R (x=s , s ) \quad \rightarrow \quad A(e^s - e^{-2s} ) = De^{-2s} $$
$$ \frac{dG_R}{dx} |_{x=s} - \frac{dG_L}{dx} |_{x=s} = \frac{1}{p} = 1 \quad \rightarrow \quad Ae^s + 2Ae^{-2s} - 2De^{-2s} = 1$$
And here I get stuck because this seems impossible to solve so its wrong, but I can't see where I went wrong! Any tips?

Hi man, actually the application $G$ isn't a function but a distribution, because you're solving it with respect to $\delta$ which is a distribution. I make an answser

Solve the question with this theorem
A solution to the following differential distribution equation in $T$ :
$$ T^{(p)}+a_{p-1}T^{(p-1)} + ... + a_0=S $$
with a $S$ a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$. Is given as :
$$ T= H(t)e^{\lambda_1 t} * ... H(t)e^{\lambda_p}*S(t)  $$
where $H(t)=1_{\mathbb{R}^+}$ is the Heavyside distribution (or said function).  And $\lambda_i$ are the roots of $X^p+....+a_0$ polynomial and $*$ represents convolutions of distributions.
Think it ends the exercise and hope it helps !
